# How do I insert my own SQL into an ASP.NET MVC 4 controller method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm writing a RESTful web service for accessing data in Azure SQL using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework.

I created a controller for a table called QuizFamilies, and VS generated the usual REST suspects: GetQuizFamilies, PutQuizFamilies, etc.

However, I want to define my own SQL that will return only specific columns and rows.

For example, in the GetQuizFamilies method, I want to specify the following:

```
SELECT QuizFamilies.ID, QuizFamilies.Title, ImageData.Uri
FROM QuizFamilies
LEFT OUTER JOIN Images ON QuizFamilies.ImagesID = Images.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImageData on Images.ImageDataID = ImageData.ID
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using EF, left outer joins can be performed via GroupJoin. More information on joins can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx. Here is another example which may help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx. As for the projection, that can be performed using an anonymous type such as

```
select new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" }
```

Your query might look something like

```
var query = from qf in context.QuizFamilies
join images in context.Images on qf.ImagesID = images.ID into quizImages
join imageData in context.ImageData on images.ImageDataID = imageData.ID into imgdata
from images in quizImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
from imageData in imgdata.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Id = qf.ID, Title = qf.Title, Uri = imageData.Uri};
```

#### Update

If you wanted to change the default Get implementation you can simply remove the code and update the method signature. You can't return an anonymous type so if you still only want those 3 fields you'll need an additional class. I would personally leave the default Get method alone and add another method

```
public class QuizFamilyTitleAndUri
{
    public String Id {get; set;}
    public String Title {get; set;}
    public Uri ImageUri {get; set;}
}

public IEnumerable<QuizFamilyTitleAndUri> GetQuizFamilies() 
{ 
    return var query = from qf in db.QuizFamilies
    join images in db.Images on qf.ImagesID = images.ID into quizImages
    join imageData in db.ImageData on images.ImageDataID = imageData.ID into imgdata
    from images in quizImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from imageData in imgdata.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new QuizFamilyTitleAndUri() { Id = qf.ID, Title = qf.Title, ImageUri = imageData.Uri};

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm asking is where can I insert my code to do what I want?

Comment: To clarify: For example, the default GET method looks like the following:

    public IEnumerable<QuizFamilies> GetQuizFamilies()
    { return db.QuizFamilies.AsEnumerable(); }

I can't step into this and I don't know how to alter its behavior. Do I derive my own class from this and override that method? Do I go into one of the Data Model files and manually do something?